# Can I add the figure in the chart (plotly js)? How can I do it?

Tags: plotly, plotly.js

I have a candlestick chart and I want to add the circle (circle must be in range, for example
x:[0,3], y:[1,2] ) in the chart over the candlestick.If it`s impossible, can you reccomend me the library for react to carry out this task.

Comment: It would be possible if you refer to the examples of additional shapes in [this reference](https://plotly.com/javascript/shapes/#circle) in your code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.